# PHP Curl, Writing to Mysql

Tags: mysql, curl

```
$ch = 

curl_init("http://example.com");
$fp = fopen("example_homepage.txt", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

This script wrote this data to a text file in JSON format:

```
{
  "from": 1,
  "to": 1,
  "total": 1,
  "currentPage": 1,
  "totalPages": 1,
  "queryTime": "0.002",
  "totalTime": "0.004",
  "canonicalUrl": "///",
  "products": [
    {
      "salePrice": 129.99,
      "sku": 9176198
    }
```

]
}

How I would insert this data into a MySQL table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://example.com'));
// read a mysql tutorial to learn how to insert the data into a mysql table
```

Ok, edit:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com');
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$a_data = json_decode($data);
```

Comment: That will not work because of the API's server configurations I want to do this dynamically, not manualy.

Comment: Sorry for this, But can you please explain to me how I would use the variables to insert it into the DB (I know how to insert data into the database but I have not done this via Curl

Comment: The curl part is already done, you don't have to know anything about curl. All the data is in $a_data. Just var_dump($a_data) and you'll see.